# SQL REGEX Assistance Needed

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, substring

I'm hoping someone can help me - I need to parse a string in SQL, but having some difficulties:

```
InstanceID="080\\9118547FEE0F3281\\cdcinvio1d1-1-\\2\\40000974084BD525\\false\\3000547FEE0F3280"
```

Any thoughts on how I can format regex to return:

```
9118547FEE0F3281
40000974084BD525
3000547FEE0F3280
```

Appreciate any assistance you can offer

```
regexp_substr(str,'\\\\([^\]+)',1,1,null,1)
```

This works in a schema browser, but the ^\ is generating an error in application.  Can this be formatted differently ?

Comment: regexp_substr(str,'\\\\([A-Z0-9]+)',1,1,null,1)

Comment: If you have found a solution, it is recommended that you post it as an answer to this question so that others may benefit from it.